# Cоответствие имен полей модели и полей таблиц EntityFramework wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет!

1. Поле идентификатор всегда должно присутствовать в модели при использовании EntityFramework?
2. Есть некая модель. Имя поля идентификатора отличается от имени поля в БД

   ```
   [Key]
   [Column("idEmployee")]
   public int id { get; set; }
   ```

Как видно из кода выше: поле в БД `idEmployee`, а в модели просто `id`. Когда я во VM делаю запрос к базе и возвращаю объект модели `context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("какой-то запрос");` Возникает ошибка не соответствия имен полей.

[image]

Это можно как-то исправить не меняя имен полей?
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Какой запрос вы отправляете? Не пробовали использовать Linq-to-Entities запросы?

Comment: @Eugen, обычный запрос на выборку с условием, в котором выбирается то самое поле-идентификатор "SELECT idEmployee FROM Users WHERE ...". С запросами Linq-to-Entities до конца не разобрался...

Comment: Попробуйте "SELECT idEmployee as id FROM Users WHERE ..." или "SELECT idEmployee id FROM Users WHERE ..."

Comment: @Eugen, спасибо, помогло! Оба варианта рабочие. А что на счет вопроса #1?

Comment: насколько я знаю id должен быть в модели, поскольку EF необходимо знать к какой именно записи обращаться при изменении\удалении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наличие идентификатора в модели желательно, поскольку Entity Framework необходимо знать к какой записи в таблице обращаться в случае удаления/изменения. В запросе присвойте алияс для столбца idEmployee, таким образом:

```
SELECT idEmployee id FROM Users WHERE ...
```